# SSL Certificate Format

Tags: c#, c++, libcrypto

I'm starting some C++ programming to read certificates with libcrypto (OpenSSL) and I'm curious about the format of a certificate ("crt" or "cert") file.

In the file, when I look at it with a text editor, there are multiple certificate sections like so:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
YYYYYYYYYYYY
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When I look at this certificate in Windows (simply by double clicking the ".crt" file, it shows only a single entry in the certificate path.  Is there some defined order to what these certificate sections are?

And on a side note, when I use C# to read the certificate like such:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"E:\somePath\device.crt");
var bytes = cert.GetRawCertData();
string temp = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

The variable temp only show contains the data from the first begin/end section in the file. That is, temp contains "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

Also the certificate is a client certificate.

So I'm curious: What are the two "certificates" in the one file?

Thanks!

Comment: We don't know. PEM and DER are just encodings. You'd have to share the files (think carefully because they might contain sensitive data). same for crt file. You can use `opensssl x509 -in filename.ext -noout -text` to inspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal cases, a `.crt` file contains just one certificate. However, in some contexts, some applications may allow that a file contains multiple certificates.

For example, some applications may expect that a file contains all or some certificates of a **certificate chain**. However, in typical cases, such file has `.p12` (PKCS#12) or `.pfx` as its extension.

[image: certificate chain]

The extension `.crt` indicates that the content of the file is a certificate, but the extension does not tell anything about the file format. The file format may be **PEM** (Privacy-Enhanced Mail) ([RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468)), **DER** (Distinguished Encoding Rules) ([X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690/)) or something else. If the file's content is text data and contains `-----BEGIN ?????----`, the file format is PEM. On the other hand, if the file contains binary data, it is highly likely that the file format is DER.

Diagrams below from *"[Illustrated X.509 Certificate](https://medium.com/@darutk/illustrated-x-509-certificate-84aece2c5c2e)"* illustrate relationship among **ASN.1** ([X.680](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680/)), **DER** ([X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690/)), **BASE64** ([RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)) and **PEM** ([RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468)).

[image: relationship among ASN.1, DER, BASE64 and PEM]

[image: relationship among ASN.1, DER, BASE64 and PEM (Application to X.509 Certificate]

I guess that the `.crt` file at your hand represents the entire or a part of a certificate chain.